# EF 5 Code First, multiple parent child with cascade delete?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have the following model:

```
public class Parent1
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public List<Contact> Contacts {get;set;}
}

public class Parent2
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public List<Contact> Contacts {get;set;}
}

public class Parent3
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public List<Contact> Contacts {get;set;}
}

public class Contact
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public Parent1 Parent1 {get;set;}
   public Parent2 Parent2 {get;set;}
   public Parent3 Parent3 {get;set;}
}
```

Is it possible to have cascade deletion in this scenario, the 3 foreign keys on Contact will be optional, is this possible to enable in EF or is there a better way of achieving this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Cascade delete is always there. The question is, are you trying to turn cascade delete on or off?

Comment: I'm trying to turn it on, the Contact class will only have 1 of those Parents associated, so in the event of deletion of any parent I want it to cascade deletion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete `Contact Object` when `Parent Object` is deleted, You must configure it from the `Parent`side of the association. Like this.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ParentEntity>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Contact)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentEntityId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);// To turn it off change to false as parameter.
```

Comment: That would make the foreign key required, which it isn't, there will be multiple parents and each foreign key is optional.